# Why can't I Selection Sort this library?

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, selection

I'm trying to use Selection Sort for a library of books so that it sorts them alphabetically, however I can't get it to work.

SelectionSort(library); doesn't work but SelectionSort(titles); does, any ideas? Thanks :)

Here is the full code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace BookSortingEx
{
    class Program
    {

        static void swap<T>(ref T x, ref T y)
        {
            //swapcount++;
            T temp = x;
            x = y;
            y = temp;
        }


        static void printArray(string[] a)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(a[i] + ",");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        static bool IsInOrder<T>(T[] a) where T : IComparable
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < a.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                if (a[i].CompareTo(a[i + 1]) > 0)
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string[] array1 = { "Fred", "Zoe", "Angela", "Umbrella", "Ben" };
            string[] titles = {"Writing Solid Code",
                "Objects First","Programming Gems",
                "Head First Java","The C Programming Language",
                "Mythical Man Month","The Art of Programming",
                "Coding Complete","Design Patterns", 
                "Problem Solving in Java"};
            string[] authors = { "Maguire", "Kolling", "Bentley", "Sierra", "Richie", "Brooks", "Knuth", "McConnal", "Gamma", "Weiss" };
            string[] isbns = { "948343", "849328493", "38948932", "394834342", "983492389", "84928334", "4839455", "21331322", "348923948", "43893284", "9483294", "9823943" };

            Book[] library = new Book[10];

            for (int i = 0; i < library.Length; i++)
            {
                library[i] = new Book(isbns[i], titles[i], authors[i]);
            }

           **DOESNT WORK - // SelectionSort(library);** 

           SelectionSort(titles);
            printArray(titles);

            foreach (Book book in library)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" {0} ", book);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadKey();

        }

        static public void SelectionSort(string[] a)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < a.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                int smallest = i;
                for (int j = i + 1; j < a.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (a[j].CompareTo(a[smallest]) < 0)
                        smallest = j;
                }
                swap(ref a[i], ref a[smallest]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `SelectionSort(string[] a)` and you are passing a `Book[]` type variable (different from `string[] titles`)

Comment: "Doesn't work" is far too vague. Please make sure you give a description of exactly what's happening.

Comment: when I use SelectionSort(library); it doesn't compile...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method expects a `string[]`, but you're giving it a `Book[]`

You'll want to change the implementation of `SelectionSort` to support Comparable Collections, as well as have `Book` implement the `IComparable` interface.

```
public class Book : IComparable
{
    // Implementation

    public int CompareTo(Book otherBook)
    {
        // Implementation
    }
}

static public void SelectionSort<T>(IList<T> a) where T : IComparable
{
    // Implementation
}
```

The advantage of this approach, is that you won't have to create a different version of `SelectionSort` for every kind of object collection you'll want to sort.

Answer (score 3):

Because `SelectionSort` takes as an argument an array of type `string` and you are passing it an array of type `Book`. `SelectionSort(titles)` works because titles is an array of type `string`.

You need to write a method that takes an array of type `Book`

```
static public void SelectionSort(Book[] books)
```

and if you haven't done this already you probably need to define a `CompareTo` method in your `Book` class, so your sorting algorithm can figure out how to sort books.